# How to handle lots of application resources in .net application?

Tags: .net, wpf, application-design, file-handling

I'm developing a wpf app which contains a dashboard with buttons ordered by category. Each button opens a resource, this can be a PDF, a video, etc. In total there are 12 categories with 60 subjects and teaching materials per category. So 720 in total.

Right now my set-up is as follows:
For each subject i store the file name of the associated learning material in the database (SubjectID:124; Title: "SomethingSmart"; Resource:"SmartPDF.pdf"). My resources are stored on my hard drive per category/folder. So when i load a subject, I look up the file name in the database en prepend the folder associated with that category and load the file.

Now something tells me this isn't the ideal set-up. First of all because all files are stored on hard drive, on a hard-coded path like this:

- C:\TeachingMaterials/Category1/pdf1.pdf
- C:\TeachingMaterials/Category1/pdf2.pdf
- C:\TeachingMaterials/Category2/pdf1.pdf
- C:\TeachingMaterials/Category2/video2.pdf

Second, deploying an application like this is just ridiculous, "Yes, first copy 200 MB of resources to your C: drive. - Oh, you don't have administrative rights you say? Then that's too bad."

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? Although the possibility of adding and removing teaching materials via the application has to remain possible.

Comment: You could store the full path to the resource or copy/move it to a directory controlled by your application 'Program Data' is a directory typically used for this. See Special Folders.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to file distribution.

First, if you're deploying in an intranet application, where you have access to some shared server location, you can store the files on a shared path. The full (absolute) path you could save in the database for each resource in question.

Second, is to store data in a user accessible folders (AppData, or similar). I also like the Russell's answer...

The other way is to store the data in the database itself as a binary content. Obviously, this increases the database size significantly, and the files aren't easily available for 'custom' access, but it's usually a good thing, because your app doesn't have to worry if someone deleted/moved/renamed the file outside of application.

Comment: I might go with your first suggestion, loading the files on to the server. This will allow multiple users to add/update/delete material through the application. This also ensures people have the latest possible material.
Another thing that comes to mind is to cache the material that has been viewed. Because if files will be downloaded each time, I'm afraid that will put a significant load on the network. Don't know if there is a caching mechanism provided in the .net environment to do this.

Comment: If you want to create a cache than it should be cached locally at the client (because if it's on the server, there's no much optimization gain since again you have to fetch the entire doc). That brings other issues: syncing with the original copy (what if someone changes it in the meantime) etc, but, in our case we found that creating document cache usually isn't worth the effort on the intranet since it's most often 1GB networks which can take a beating of the doc transfer very easily...

Comment: I guess I'll put caching somewhat further down the line. I'll wait and see what performance I'll achieve with all files on the server. Thanks for the advice and the feedback!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) to store your files.  This is a .NET framework supported file storage area for your app so users can install the files.

Alternatively you can use relative paths, and store them in a sub directory of the installation directory.

eg:

- MyWPFApp.exe
- Resources\
- Resources\pdf1.pdf ...

You could also add them as resources and edit the resource properties from embedded to copy to output directory.

Comment: It is better to have the files separate to your application file.  This will make the app easier to maintain.

Comment: Like I said above, I'll probably work out a solution with resources placed on a server folder because of the 'collaborative nature' of the app (so to speak :-)) Thanks for the input though!